# Gui window in java does not fully show off my code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I wrote this gui based code for a trivia, where it shows the first page where you can click start button to start the quiz. It worked, however, when it goes to the actual quiz window, it only shows few questions instead of showing all 15 and displays the result very quickly.. I wasn't able to find out what's wrong, though I'm assuming it is because of the public class actionListener. Although, I don't have an idea to fix it out. I would appreciate if someone gives some help..

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Practice implements ActionListener{
    
    
    String[] questions =    {
                                "Select the official name of the coronavirus.",
                                "When did the corona virus first ecountered?",
                                "What is the percentage of people recovering from the coronavirus?",
                                "Which below is NOT the symptom of coronavirus?",
                                "Which part of the human body does the    coronavirus attach itself to?",
                                "How many hour can the coronavirus survive on plastic and stainless steel surfaces?",
                                "Whihc human organs in the body does the coronavirus attack?",
                                "How large is the coronavirus?",
                                "Which is a safe distance to stay apart from people? ",
                                "Who has the highest risk of getting infected by coronvirus?",
                                "When should face masks be worn?",
                                "Which is more effective for removing the coronavirus from your hands?",
                                "Which industry includes workers with increased exposure-risk?",
                                "What is the period of quartine?",
                                "What is the name of the city where coronavirus    was first detected?"
                                
                            };
    String[][] options =    {
                                {"COVID-19","Sars-CoV-2","Zaire ebolavirus","Influenza"},
                                {"2018","2020","2017","2019"},
                                {"63%","71%","80%","76%"},
                                {"Fever","Blurred vision","Dry Cough","Nasal Congestion"},
                                {"Red Blood Cells", "Antigens", "White Blood Cells", "Ace-2 recpetors in the airways"},
                                {"4-8 hours", "72 hours and more", "45-60 hours", "90 hours and more" },
                                {"Liver", "Lungs", "Heart", "Kidney"},
                                {"8000 billionths of metre in diameter", "800 billionths of metre in diameter","80 billionths of metre in diameter","8 billionths of metre in diameter"},
                                {"3 feet(1 meter)", "2 feet(60 cm)", "1 foot (30cm)", "4.2 feet(1.3 meter)"},
                                {"Children", "Pregnant Women", "People over 60 years of age", "30-40 years agr of men"},
                                {"Public Transport", "Confined or Crowed spaces", "Small restaurants or shops", "All of the above"},
                                {"Soap and water", "Alcohol-based hand sanitiser","Detergent", "Face cleanser"},
                                {"Health care", "Airline operations", "Waste management", "All of the above"},
                                {"21 days","7 days", "14 days", "6 days"},
                                {"Wuhan", "Hubei", "Hunan","Shanghai"}
                            };
    char[] answers =        {
                                'A',
                                'D',
                                'C',
                                'B',
                                'D',
                                'B',
                                'B',
                                'C',
                                'A',
                                'C',
                                'D',
                                'A',
                                'D',
                                'B',
                                'A'
                            };
    
    char guess;
    char answer;
    int index;
    int correct_guesses =0;
    int total_questions = questions.length;
    int result;
    int seconds=15;
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    
    JTextField textName = new JTextField();
    JTextArea subtitle = new JTextArea();
    JButton startButton = new JButton();
    
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField();
    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
    JButton buttonA = new JButton();
    JButton buttonB = new JButton();
    JButton buttonC = new JButton();
    JButton buttonD = new JButton();
    JLabel answer_labelA = new JLabel();
    JLabel answer_labelB = new JLabel();
    JLabel answer_labelC = new JLabel();
    JLabel answer_labelD = new JLabel();
    JLabel time_label = new JLabel();
    JLabel seconds_left = new JLabel();
    JTextField number_right = new JTextField();
    JTextField percentage = new JTextField();
    
    Timer timer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            seconds--;
            seconds_left.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
            if(seconds<=0) {
                displayAnswer();
            }
            }
        });
    
public Practice() {
    
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(204,229,255));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        
        textName.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 170);
        textName.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        textName.setForeground(new Color(0,76,153));
        textName.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,85));
        textName.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(2));
        textName.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        textName.setText("Trivia!");
        textName.setEditable(false);
        
        
        
        
        startButton.setFont(new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN,25));
        startButton.setBounds(225, 440, 250, 100);
        startButton.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        startButton.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        startButton.setText("START");
        startButton.addActionListener(this);

    
        frame.add(startButton);
        
        frame.add(textName);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
}
public void nextScreen() {  
    
        textName.setVisible(false);
        startButton.setVisible(false);
        subtitle.setVisible(false);
    
        textfield.setBounds(0,0,700,70);
        textfield.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        textfield.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        textfield.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,33));
        textfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
        textfield.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        textfield.setEditable(false);
        
        textarea.setBounds(0,70,700,90);
        textarea.setLineWrap(true);
        textarea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textarea.setBackground(new Color(204,229,255));
        textarea.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        textarea.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,30));
        textarea.setLocation(16, 84);
        textarea.setEditable(false);
        
        buttonA.setBounds(50,200,50,50);
        buttonA.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,33));
        buttonA.setFocusable(false);
        buttonA.addActionListener(this);
        buttonA.setText("A");
        
        buttonB.setBounds(50,300,50,50);
        buttonB.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,33));
        buttonB.setFocusable(false);
        buttonB.addActionListener(this);
        buttonB.setText("B");
        
        buttonC.setBounds(50,400,50,50);
        buttonC.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,33));
        buttonC.setFocusable(false);
        buttonC.addActionListener(this);
        buttonC.setText("C");
        
        buttonD.setBounds(50,500,50,50);
        buttonD.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,33));
        buttonD.setFocusable(false);
        buttonD.addActionListener(this);
        buttonD.setText("D");
        
        answer_labelA.setBounds(130,175,500,100);
        answer_labelA.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        answer_labelA.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        answer_labelA.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,26));
        
        answer_labelB.setBounds(130,275,500,100);
        answer_labelB.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        answer_labelB.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        answer_labelB.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,26));
        
        answer_labelC.setBounds(130,375,500,100);
        answer_labelC.setBackground(new Color(50,50,50));
        answer_labelC.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        answer_labelC.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,26));
        
        answer_labelD.setBounds(130,475,500,100);
        answer_labelD.setBackground(new Color(204,229,255));
        answer_labelD.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
        answer_labelD.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,26));
        
        seconds_left.setBounds(150,575,100,70);
        seconds_left.setBackground(new Color(204,229,255));
        seconds_left.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 255));
        seconds_left.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,37));
        seconds_left.setOpaque(true);
        seconds_left.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        seconds_left.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
        
        time_label.setBounds(50,575,100,70);
        time_label.setBackground(new Color(204,229,255));
        time_label.setForeground(new Color(102, 102, 255));
        time_label.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.PLAIN,35));
        time_label.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        time_label.setText("Timer");
        
        number_right.setBounds(225,225,200,100);
        number_right.setBackground(new Color(153,204,255));
        number_right.setForeground(new Color(0, 102, 204));
        number_right.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,50));
        number_right.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
        number_right.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        number_right.setEditable(false);
        
        percentage.setBounds(225,325,200,100);
        percentage.setBackground(new Color(153,204,255));
        percentage.setForeground(new Color(0,102,204));
        percentage.setFont(new Font("PT Serif",Font.BOLD,50));
        percentage.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
        percentage.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        percentage.setEditable(false);
        
        frame.add(time_label);
        frame.add(seconds_left);
        frame.add(answer_labelA);
        frame.add(answer_labelB);
        frame.add(answer_labelC);
        frame.add(answer_labelD);
        frame.add(buttonA);
        frame.add(buttonB);
        frame.add(buttonC);
        frame.add(buttonD);
        frame.add(textarea);
        frame.add(textfield);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        nextQuestion();
    }

    public void nextQuestion() {
        
        if(index>=total_questions) {
            results();
        }
        else {
            textfield.setText("Question "+(index+1));
            textarea.setText(questions[index]);
            answer_labelA.setText(options[index][0]);
            answer_labelB.setText(options[index][1]);
            answer_labelC.setText(options[index][2]);
            answer_labelD.setText(options[index][3]);
            timer.start();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            nextScreen();
        
            buttonA.setEnabled(false);
            buttonB.setEnabled(false);
            buttonC.setEnabled(false);
            buttonD.setEnabled(false);
            
            if(e.getSource()==buttonA) {
                answer= 'A';
                if(answer == answers[index]) {
                    correct_guesses++;
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource()==buttonB) {
                answer= 'B';
                if(answer == answers[index]) {
                    correct_guesses++;
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource()==buttonC) {
                answer= 'C';
                if(answer == answers[index]) {
                    correct_guesses++;
                }
            }
            if(e.getSource()==buttonD) {
                answer= 'D';
                if(answer == answers[index]) {
                    correct_guesses++;
                }
            }
            displayAnswer();
    }
    public void displayAnswer() {
        
        timer.stop();
        
        buttonA.setEnabled(false);
        buttonB.setEnabled(false);
        buttonC.setEnabled(false);
        buttonD.setEnabled(false);
        
        if(answers[index] != 'A')
            answer_labelA.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        if(answers[index] != 'B')
            answer_labelB.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        if(answers[index] != 'C')
            answer_labelC.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        if(answers[index] != 'D')
            answer_labelD.setForeground(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        
        Timer pause = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                answer_labelA.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
                answer_labelB.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
                answer_labelC.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
                answer_labelD.setForeground(new Color(0,25,51));
                
                answer = ' ';
                seconds=15;
                seconds_left.setText(String.valueOf(seconds));
                buttonA.setEnabled(true);
                buttonB.setEnabled(true);
                buttonC.setEnabled(true);
                buttonD.setEnabled(true);
                index++;
                nextQuestion();
            }
        });
        pause.setRepeats(false);
        pause.start();
    }
    public void results(){
        
        buttonA.setEnabled(false);
        buttonB.setEnabled(false);
        buttonC.setEnabled(false);
        buttonD.setEnabled(false);
        
        result = (int)((correct_guesses/(double)total_questions)*100);
        
        textfield.setText("RESULTS!");
        textarea.setText("");
        answer_labelA.setText("");
        answer_labelB.setText("");
        answer_labelC.setText("");
        answer_labelD.setText("");
        
        number_right.setText("("+correct_guesses+"/"+total_questions+")");
        percentage.setText(result+"%");
        
        frame.add(number_right);
        frame.add(percentage);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You should create a class to hold the question, possible answers, and correct answer.  That organizes your information and makes it easier to verify that your quiz information is correct.  Next, go through the Oracle tutorial Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing.  You are doing so many things wrong that I can't bear to look at your code for more than 10 seconds.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: The other commenter is sadly correct, despite that maybe being a quite frustrating realization. You should most definitely learn some more about using Swing effectively. Some pointers on what is most obvious and what makes this code so hard to debug/review: 1) Separate your Model from your View. As the other commenter suggested, you should probably have classes for your data and a separate class for your UI. This class is doing way too much. 2) Do not use `null` layout! Rather use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)!

Comment: 3) The code associated to the buttonactions is also kind of a messy solution (personally not at all a fan of implementing `ActionListener` and the hack of checking the source of the `ActionEvent`). Adding a listener instance to each button is also senseless. Maybe using a combination of [ButtonGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) and [JToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) is more intuitive and clean.

Comment: A classmate is having a really [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63115171/2180785) why don't you guys work together to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes

1)Only one question shows up on the frame that way the user can focus only on that question and can progress to the next only when either he gives his answer or the question times out[5 sceonds per question]

2)I have moved all the Q/A to an text file which must be placed in the same package as the other classes. That way new question's can be added easily in the specified format

3)Removed the use of `setBounds()` and left that job to [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and then let the frame decide it's own size using `frame.pack()`

**quiz.txt**

```
Question=Select the official name of the coronavirus.
Options=COVID-19,Sars-CoV-2,Zaire ebolavirus,Influenza
Answer=A

Question=When did the corona virus first ecountered?
Options=2018,2020,2017,2019
Answer=D

Question=What is the percentage of people recovering from the coronavirus?
Options=63%,71%,80%,76%
Answer=C

Question=Which below is NOT the symptom of coronavirus?
Options=Fever,Blurred vision,Dry Cough,Nasal Congestion
Answer=B

Question=Which part of the human body does the    coronavirus attach itself to?
Options=Red Blood Cells, Antigens, White Blood Cells, Ace-2 recpetors in the airways
Answer=D

Question=How many hour can the coronavirus survive on plastic and stainless steel surfaces?
Options=4-8 hours, 72 hours and more, 45-60 hours, 90 hours and more
Answer=B

Question=Which human organs in the body does the coronavirus attack?
Options=Liver, Lungs, Heart, Kidney
Answer=B

Question=How large is the coronavirus?
Options=8000 billionths of metre in diameter, 800 billionths of metre in diameter,80 billionths of metre in diameter,8 billionths of metre in diameter
Answer=C

Question=Which is a safe distance to stay apart from people?
Options=3 feet(1 meter), 2 feet(60 cm), 1 foot (30cm), 4.2 feet(1.3 meter)
Answer=A

Question=Who has the highest risk of getting infected by coronvirus?
Options=Children, Pregnant Women, People over 60 years of age, 30-40 years agr of men
Answer=C

Question=When should face masks be worn?
Options=Public Transport, Confined or Crowed spaces, Small restaurants or shops, All of the above
Answer=D

Question=Which is more effective for removing the coronavirus from your hands?
Options=Soap and water, Alcohol-based hand sanitiser,Detergent, Face cleanser
Answer=A

Question=Which industry includes workers with increased exposure-risk?
Options=Health care, Airline operations, Waste management, All of the above
Answer=D

Question=What is the period of quartine?
Options=21 days,7 days, 14 days, 6 days
Answer=B

Question=What is the name of the city where coronavirus  was first detected?
Options=Wuhan, Hubei, Hunan,Shanghai
Answer=A
```

**QuizLoader.java**

```
final class QuizLoader 
{
 static String question;
 static List<String> options;
 static char answer;
 
 
 static Question loadQuiz()
 {
  try
  {
   List<Question> questions=new ArrayList();

   Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(QuizLoader.class.getResource("quiz.txt").toURI()))
        .stream()
        .map(line->line.trim())
        .filter(line->!line.isBlank() && !line.isEmpty())
        .forEach(line->
        {
         String lineInfo[]=line.trim().split("=");
         
         switch(lineInfo[0])
         {
          case "Question":question=lineInfo[1];
          break;
          case "Options":options=Arrays.asList(lineInfo[1].split(","));
          break;
          default:questions.add(new Question(question,options,lineInfo[1].charAt(0)));
         }
        });

   int size=questions.size();
   for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++)
   {
    Question
    current=questions.get(i),
    next=questions.get(i+1);
    
    current.nextQuestion=next;
   }
   
   return questions.get(0);
  }
  catch(IOException | URISyntaxException ex)
  {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable To Load Quiz "+ex.getMessage());
   
   System.exit(0);
  }
  
  return null;
 }

 static final class Question
 {
  public final String question;
  public final HashMap<Character,String> options=new HashMap();
  public final char answer;
  
  public Question nextQuestion;
  //ASCII Value OF 'A'=65,B='66' so on
  public Question(String question,List<String> options,char answer)
  {
   this.question=question;
   
   int size=options.size();
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++){this.options.put((char)(i+65),options.get(i));}
   
   this.answer=Character.toUpperCase(answer);
  }
  
  public int getAnswer(){return (int)((answer)-65);}
  public boolean isCorrect(int finalAnswer){return (char)(finalAnswer+65)==answer;}
 }
}
```

**Questionpanel.java**

```
final class QuestionPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
 private final InfoPanel infoPanel;
 private final OptionsPanel options;
 private final ResponsePanel response;
 
 private final Question thisQuestion;
 private int nextQuestionIn=3;
 private final Timer timer=new Timer(1000,this);
 
 QuestionPanel(QuizPanel mainPanel,Question question)
 {
  super(new BorderLayout(0,30));
  
  this.thisQuestion=question;
  
  add(infoPanel=new InfoPanel(question.question),BorderLayout.NORTH);
  
  add(options=new OptionsPanel(question.options,question.answer),BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  add(response=new ResponsePanel(mainPanel),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  
  setBackground(Color.white);
  
  timer.start();
 }
 
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
  boolean timeUp=infoPanel.decreaseTimeLeft();
  
  if(timeUp)
  {
   options.highLightAnswer(null);
   
   nextQuestionIn--;
   
   if(nextQuestionIn==0)
   {
    timer.stop();
    
    response.actions[2].doClick();
   }
  }
 }
 
 private final class InfoPanel extends JPanel
 {
  private final JLabel timeLeft; 
  
  private InfoPanel(String questionTxt)
  {
   super(new BorderLayout());
   
   add(create(questionTxt,JLabel.LEFT),BorderLayout.WEST);
   
   add(timeLeft=create("5 Seconds Left",JLabel.RIGHT),BorderLayout.EAST);
   
   setOpaque(false);
  }
  
  private JLabel create(String text,int textPosition)
  {
   JLabel label=new JLabel(text);
   
   label.setHorizontalAlignment(textPosition);
   
   return label;
  }
  
  private boolean decreaseTimeLeft()
  {
   int timeLeftInt=Integer.parseInt(""+timeLeft.getText().charAt(0));
   
   if(timeLeftInt==0){return true;}
   
   timeLeftInt--;
   
   timeLeft.setText(timeLeftInt+" Seconds Left");
   
   if(timeLeftInt<3){timeLeft.setForeground(Color.red);}
   
   return false;
  }
 }
 
 private final class OptionsPanel extends JPanel
 {
  private final char rightAnswer;
  private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup=new ButtonGroup();
  
  OptionsPanel(HashMap<Character,String> optionsMap,char rightAnswer)
  {
   super(new GridLayout(4,1,0,20));
   
   setOpaque(false);
   
   JRadioButton[] options=new JRadioButton[optionsMap.size()];
   
   optionsMap.entrySet().forEach(entry->
   {
    int index=((int)(entry.getKey()))-65;
    
    options[index]=new JRadioButton();
    
    options[index].setActionCommand(""+entry.getKey());
    
    options[index].setText(entry.getValue());
   
    options[index].setOpaque(false);
    
    buttonGroup.add(options[index]);
    
    add(options[index]);
   });
   
   this.rightAnswer=rightAnswer;
  
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));
  }
  
  private void highLightAnswer(String selected)
  {
   Enumeration<AbstractButton> allOptions=buttonGroup.getElements();
   
   while(allOptions.hasMoreElements())
   {
    JRadioButton option=(JRadioButton)allOptions.nextElement();
      
    String action=option.getActionCommand();
    if(action.equals(""+rightAnswer))
    {
     option.setSelected(true);
     
     option.setForeground(Color.green);
    }
    else if(selected!=null && action.equals(selected) && !selected.equals(""+rightAnswer)){option.setForeground(Color.red);}
    
    option.setEnabled((selected!=null && action.equals(selected)) || action.equals(""+rightAnswer));
   }
  }
  
  private boolean verifyAnswer()
  {
   String selected=buttonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
   
   timer.stop();
   
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,selected.equals(""+rightAnswer)?"Correct":"Wrong Right Answer Is "+rightAnswer);
   
   highLightAnswer(selected);
   
   return selected.equals(""+rightAnswer);
  }
 }
 
 private final class ResponsePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
 {
  private final QuizPanel quizPanel;
  private boolean response;
  private final JButton actions[]=new JButton[3];
  
  private ResponsePanel(QuizPanel quizPanel)
  {
   super(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING,50,0));
   
   setOpaque(false);
   
   this.quizPanel=quizPanel;
   
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
    actions[i]=new JButton();
    
    switch(i)
    {
     case 0:actions[i].setText("I Give Up");
     break;
     case 1:actions[i].setText("Confirm");
     break;
     default:actions[i].setText("Next Question");
    }
    
    actions[i].setActionCommand(""+i);
    
    actions[i].addActionListener(ResponsePanel.this);
    
    actions[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,30));
    
    add(actions[i]);
   }
  }
  
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   String action=e.getActionCommand();
   
   if(action.equals("0") || action.equals("1"))
   {
    timer.stop();
    switch(action)
    {
     case "0":options.highLightAnswer(null);
     break;
     default:response=options.verifyAnswer();
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){actions[i].setEnabled(false);}
   }
   else
   {
    timer.stop();
    
    quizPanel.setQuestion(response,thisQuestion.nextQuestion);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

**QuizPanel.java**

```
final class QuizPanel extends JPanel
{
 private final JFrame mainFrame;
 private final Question firstQuestion;
 private int score=0;
 
 QuizPanel(JFrame mainFrame)
 {
  super(new BorderLayout());
  
  this.mainFrame=mainFrame;
  
  this.firstQuestion=QuizLoader.loadQuiz();
  
  add(new QuestionPanel(QuizPanel.this,firstQuestion));
 }
 
 void setQuestion(boolean addScore,Question question)
 {
  if(addScore){score++;}
   
  removeAll();

  add(question!=null?new QuestionPanel(this,question):new TryAgainPanel());

  revalidate();

  repaint();
  
  mainFrame.pack();
 }
 
 private final class TryAgainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
 {
  private TryAgainPanel()
  {
   super(new BorderLayout(0,50));
   
   JLabel msg=new JLabel("Your Score Is "+score);
   
   msg.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
   
   msg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,50));
   
   add(msg,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   
   JButton tryAgain=new JButton("Try Again?");
   
   tryAgain.addActionListener(TryAgainPanel.this);
   
   tryAgain.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
   
   add(tryAgain,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   score=0;
   
   setQuestion(false,firstQuestion);
  }
 }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main 
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  JFrame main=new JFrame("");
  
  main.setContentPane(new QuizPanel(main));
  
  main.pack();
  
  main.setResizable(false);
  
  main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  
  main.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

If you would like all the questions to show up on the same page you can create an scroll pane containing an JPanel with box layout along Y axis and add all the QuestionPanel's there but that would take up a lot of memory in my openion but see what work's for you